# Recreate Directory Structure and extract Files From byte array of a zip file in Java

Tags: java, file, zip

I have a byte array of zip File , I need to create zip file from that and than unzip the files and folders inside that .

I tries to do that but getting zip entries null

```
{
ResponseEntity<byte[]> result = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toString(), HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, byte[].class);
    ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBody()))
    ZipEntry entry = null;
    while ((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null)
}
```

Zip File is like

- DIR -> b.txt
- DIR -> x.php ,a.txt

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How are you getting those bytes?  Also, you should include the code which attempts to obtain a ZipEntry.

Comment: {ResponseEntity<byte[]> result = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toString(), HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, byte[].class);ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBody()))
        ZipEntry entry = null;
        while ((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) } Getting those bytes via rest template

Comment: If result.getBody() returns a byte array which represents a correct zip content, then your code would extract the zip entries also correctly. Your problem seems to be that the received byte array is not correct. So your question boils down to be a question about receiving a correct byte array through your REST framework.

Comment: Yes, this is a valid zip file. Downloading it manually and feeding it directly to the ZipInputStream yields valid results. Your problem is definitively how to get the content of this file programmatically. Since you do not provide any info about the used REST client framework I cannot give more help. Is it spring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I succeeded with download the file of your above link programmatically:

```
        List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> result = restTemplate.exchange( "someurl deleted On purpose",
                                                               HttpMethod.GET,
                                                               httpEntity,
                                                               byte[].class );

        ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBody()));
        ZipEntry entry = null;
        while ((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println( "entry: " + entry );
        }
```

The output is:

```
entry: bridge2cart/
entry: bridge2cart/config.php
entry: bridge2cart/bridge.php
entry: readme.txt
```

So you might not request the correct media type, or the URL is not correctly encoded.

Comment: Thanks @Heri I think i didn't put MediaType

Comment: Then it would be nice to upvote my answer, or select it as the correct one

Comment: I had upvoted but don't have enough points .so upvote is not visible